# Testing frontend webpages solve selenium-ide issues or change to so?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-ide, selenium-side-runner

i'm using selenium ide to test webapp frontend webpages.
I'd like to test via cli AND via gui having to mantain one scripts only.

When automating tests via selenium-side-runner it does not handle alert/confirm command if i don't change any "choose ok on next confirmation" with "webdriver choose ok on visible confirmation", but after change it side gui does not handle it.
Even exporting to python has some incokmpatiblity with gui.

Anyone knows the proper way to record a side.script with gui and run with cli without having to modify it and letting run the tests with the gui again?

I've see many complaining about this without solution, do you advise to use another fronted tester in the place of side? Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just reporting what said on github's bug tracker issue [1270](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/1270) by toddtarsi.

There's no way to have one script only to handle gui and cli tests. We have to wait for selenium-ide v4 (not SELENIUM).

The correct way is webdriver one.